# Windows Event Log

Tags: c#, .net, windows, vb.net, visual-studio

I am developing an app to capture event logs (security) from multiple Windows systems. I have a handler to EntryWritten. I am able to map most fields from the Event Viewer to the EntryWrittenEventArgs entry in .net. However, I cannot seem to find the mappings for the Level, OpCode and Task Category fields which show up in Event Viewer. Any ideas on how I get this in vb.net or c#? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `EventLog` class in the `System.Diagnostics` namespace does not contain fields for `Level`, `OpCode` or `Task`. There is, however, the `EventRecord` class in the `System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader` namespace which is capable of returning those fields. Note that this namespace is **mainly used for retrieving event logs from a remote machine**. Even though you could use it to get logs on the local machine as well, it opens a local pipe to the system, which makes it slower than the `EventLog` class. If you really need to access those fields though, this is how this class is generally used:

```
    private void LoadEventLogs()
    {
        List<EventRecord> eventLogs = new List<EventRecord>();

        EventLogSession session = new EventLogSession();

        foreach (string logName in session.GetLogNames())
        {
            EventLogQuery query = new EventLogQuery(logName, PathType.LogName);
            query.TolerateQueryErrors = true;
            query.Session = session;

            EventLogWatcher logWatcher = new EventLogWatcher(query);
            logWatcher.EventRecordWritten += 
                   new EventHandler<EventRecordWrittenEventArgs>(LogWatcher_EventRecordWritten);

            try
            {
                logWatcher.Enabled = true;
            }
            catch (EventLogException) { }


            // This is how you'd read the logs
            //using (EventLogReader reader = new EventLogReader(query))
            //{
            //    for (EventRecord eventInstance = reader.ReadEvent(); eventInstance != null; eventInstance = reader.ReadEvent())
            //    {
            //        eventLogs.Add(eventInstance);
            //    }
            //}
        }
    }
```

And the `LogWatcher_EventRecordWritten` event handler:

```
 private void LogWatcher_EventRecordWritten(object sender, EventRecordWrittenEventArgs e)
    {
        var level = e.EventRecord.Level;
        var task = e.EventRecord.TaskDisplayName;
        var opCode = e.EventRecord.OpcodeDisplayName;
        // Other properties
    }
```

Note that I wrapped the `logWatcher.Enabled = true;` statement in a `try-catch` block, because not all sources allow entry-written listeners (security should work fine). The commented-out section shows you an example of reading all the logs, if you need it.

Comment: Digging in the grave yard for this post, my apologies.  But, wouldn't you need to have this in a while loop to keep it running?  I'm trying something similar on a different domain.